# mv files from one folder to another 40GB at a time

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, mv

I have a folder `/x/` with lots of sub folders and sub files. I need to move everything in `/x/` to `/y/` but I need to do so 40GB at a time. I was doing `mv /x/a*` and then the next day `mv /x/b*` but sometimes that might mean a lot of files were moved or very little. I need something more predictable. I would like to run `mv /x/*` but somehow limit it to 40GB of total files being moved. What are my options? Not that it's needed but I will be putting this in `.sh` script and using a cron.

Thanks =)

Edit: I marked the best answer but it does not work for my case. I'm using ACD_CLI to upload my backups and other files to the Amazon Cloud Drive. What I did was go about the problem backward. My problem was how do I upload large amounts of files without saturating my bandwidth during the day. I work from home so skype meeting and what not. The answer was to turn on QOS on my router. I can now upload 24/7 and my skype and other traffic takes precedent over my file upload.It was a great solution marked below and I know it well help other people in the future.

Comment: Do you have enough space on the source to use Rinzwind's solution?

Comment: 1 thing: I believe you asked for the wrong solution. I would use "rsync" and have that copy or move all the files. It can be told to skip files that are the same so you can start it. Stop it at any time. Restart it and it would skip the already copied files.

Comment: And that would also solve another possible issue: if a file changed in between the time you start and finish this it will be copied again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a compressed tar file of all the files you need to move, split the tar file into 40Gb size chunks and move those 1 at a time.  When done cat the files back to 1 large tar file and untar it.

An example:

1. create an archive

   ```
   tar -zcvf file.tar.gz /directory/*
   ```

   - c create
   - z compress
   - v verbose
   - f use a file as a target
2. split them up

   ```
       split -b 40M file.tar.gz
   ```

   (by default) it will create files starting with xaa, xab, xac of roughly 40Mb each.
3. Move them to the new place.
4. Recreate the file

   ```
    cat x* > file.tar.gz
   ```
5. and untar it ...

   ```
   tar xvfz file.tar.gz .
   ```

Comment: Smart & simple!

Comment: This is great and I marked as right because I searched all over the internet and this is the best answer but it doesn't work for me =/, I will explain in the question.

Comment: @Levi make it an answer and accept yours. Ill hitch along with my answer ;-)  Instances are a nightmare for things like this. We use the "copy-files" over "ssh" for our google instances with a dedicated VPN.

Comment: @Rinzwind Nope! You had the correct answer for my original question =). I should have asked the best way to do it, thankfully I came to the correct conclusion. Now I got 2-3 weeks of 24/7 uploading to do.